# Regex pattern to replace string containing special characters

Tags: regex, uipath, uipath-studio

Need help finding out the regex pattern that will help me replacing below -

`*LABEL` and it’s value which contains within double quote.
(Text within double quotes may contain all different special characters and there is no fix pattern)

I am giving 2 different examples -

Input String 1 -

```
*QUESTION 99924 *ALPHA 1026L3 *DUMMY *VAR “version” *LABEL “SCRIPT VERSION” *PROPERTIES “ReportType=IsShell;ExcludeFromDAU=True”
```

Expected Output String -

```
*QUESTION 99924 *ALPHA 1026L3 *DUMMY *VAR “version” *PROPERTIES “ReportType=IsShell;ExcludeFromDAU=True”
```

Input String 2 -

```
*QUESTION 270 *CODES 4705L996 *RANDOM *MULTI *MIN 1 *LABEL “BARRIERS_TO_ATTENDENCE - B3” *VAR “BARRIERS_TO_ATTENDENCE” *PROPERTIES “DIMVAR=BARRIERS_TO_ATTENDENCE” *IF [#Q180,1] UIOPTIONS "? ROWPICKER"
```

Expected Output String -

```
*QUESTION 270 *CODES 4705L996 *RANDOM *MULTI *MIN 1 *VAR “BARRIERS_TO_ATTENDENCE” *PROPERTIES “DIMVAR=BARRIERS_TO_ATTENDENCE” *IF [#Q180,1] UIOPTIONS "? ROWPICKER"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\*LABEL\s?“([^”])*”
```

The above regex will match any occurrence of *LABEL followed by an optional whitespace, then your opening character and anything *except* your closing character, ”, and finally the closing character, ”.

If you need to remove the space after the label-flag, you can extend the regex like so:

```
\*LABEL\s?“([^”])*”\s?
```

NOTE, the capture group (marked by the parenthesis) is optional and can be reduced to `\*LABEL\s?“[^”]*”\s?`.

Comment: Yes, I needed to remove the additional space as well after label-flag, hence tried with the 2nd pattern that you shared - \*LABEL\s?"[^"]*"\s?
It is working fine.

Thanks a lot for the quick help.. really appreciate!!